# Mathematica, increasing by 2n+1, not, say 3

Tags: random, wolfram-mathematica

Here's what I have.

```
RandomChoice[{.5, .5} -> {Heads, Tails}, 3]
```

then I write

```
RandomChoice[{.5, .5} -> {Heads, Tails}, 5]
```

How do I increase this function by increments of 2n+1?

Comment: @Gabe You might want to edit the title. In the present case, the size (ie cardinality) of the output sets is 2 n +1, but this increases by 2.  I'm not sure what to suggest but perhaps you can think of a better title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpreted your request as indicating you wanted the function, 2n + 1, with increments of 2. So the values would be: 3, 5, 7, 9, 11...If that is the correct interpretation then the following should work:

```
Table[RandomChoice[{heads, tails}, 2 n + 1], {n, 1, 10}]
```

So, f(n) = 2 n + 1 for the domain of {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

You can achieve the same result with:

```
Table[RandomChoice[{heads, tails}, n], {n, 3, 21, 2}]
```

This makes it even clearer that the increment is 2. However it is not the same function.  The target is the same as before but the domain is now the same as the target set: {3, 5, 7...21}

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++, Print[RandomChoice[{.5, .5} -> {Heads, Tails}, 2i+1]]]
```

Which would give a sample output of:

```
{Heads, Tails, Tails}
{Tails, Tails, Heads, Heads, Tails}
{Tails, Tails, Heads, Tails, Heads, Heads, Tails}
{Heads, Heads, Tails, Tails, Heads, Tails, Heads, Tails, Tails}
```

This also does the same thing:

```
Do[Print[RandomChoice[{.5, .5} -> {Heads, Tails}, 2i+1]], {i, 4}]
```

I don't know if there is a more elegant/efficient way of doing this, since I'm new to Mathematica - but I'm sure someone will comment if there is.

Comment: @Alex Your code seems to work fine. You can eliminate `{.5, .5}->` because `RandomChoice` will assign equal weights by default. Generally one tries to avoid looping constructs in Mma, but this is more a question of programming style rather than correctness or efficiency.

Comment: @Alex In Mathematica, iteration is a last resource, and usually comes with big performance penalties. It's more natural to use list-wide operations.

Comment: @belisarius : Thanks for the info, I'll go do some reading about it :)

Comment: @Alex For example `Array[RandomChoice[{heads, tails}, 2 # + 1] &, 10]` does the same without loops and without using variables.